# Converting audio formats with libav in c on linux

Tags: audio, mp3, encode, libav, resampling

I am trying to write an app, where part of it converts an audio file to a different format. But the output is garbage (well, that's what it looks like in audacity).

After trying many different things, I ended up with this: a raw audio file that I try to convert and write out as an MP3 file. I know the raw audio is OK (via audacity). But the MP3 again is garbage.

Here is the code I am using (I pieced this together from the libav examples):

```
/*
 * flac2mp3.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Aug 20, 2014
 *      Author: ken
 */



#include <stddef.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <exception>      // std::exception
#include <cerrno>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/types.h>

#ifndef __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>
#endif
#ifndef INT64_C
#define INT64_C(c) (c ## LL)
#define UINT64_C(c) (c ## ULL)
#endif

extern "C"
{
#include <libavutil/avassert.h>
#include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
#include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>

#ifdef CPP_W_LITERAL_SUFFIX
#undef CPP_W_LITERAL_SUFFIX
#include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
#define CPP_W_LITERAL_SUFFIX
#endif
#ifdef av_err2str
#undef  av_err2str
#endif
#define av_err2str(errnum) \
    av_make_error_string((char*)(__builtin_alloca(AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE)),\
    AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, errnum)

#ifdef av_ts2timestr
#undef  av_ts2timestr
#endif
#define av_ts2timestr(ts, tb) \
        av_ts_make_time_string((char*)(__builtin_alloca(AV_TS_MAX_STRING_SIZE)), ts, tb)

}

typedef unsigned char   BYTE;
#include <algorithm>
#include <fcntl.h>

static AVFormatContext *encfmt_ctx = NULL;
static AVCodecContext *audio_enc_ctx;
static AVStream *audio_encstream = NULL;
static int audio_frame_deccount = 0, audio_frame_enccount = 0;
static SwrContext *swr;
static BYTE **outpb;
static const BYTE **inpb;

#define MP3_SAMPLE_FMT  AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P
#define MP3_BITRATE     256000
#define MP3_SAMPLE_RATE 44100

#define FLAC_SAMPLE_FMT AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16
#define FLAC_BITRATE        256000
#define FLAC_SAMPLE_RATE    44100

#define SAMPLES_TO_CB(stc, cs)  (av_get_bytes_per_sample(stc->codec->sample_fmt) * stc->codec->channels * cs)
#define SAMPLES_FROM_CB(stc, cb) cb/(av_get_bytes_per_sample(stc->codec->sample_fmt) * stc->codec->channels)

#define BYTES_TO_READ   2048

bool encode_buffer(BYTE* buff, int cbdec, bool flush)
{
    int ret;
    int got_frame;
    int line_size;
    AVPacket    epkt = {0};
    AVFrame *eframe = avcodec_alloc_frame();

    av_init_packet(&epkt);
    /*
     * convert audio
     */
    long int c_insamples = cbdec/(4);
//  long int delay = swr_get_delay(swr,(long int) 44100);
    long int delay = 0;
    int c_outsamples = av_rescale_rnd(delay + c_insamples,
            (long int) MP3_SAMPLE_RATE,
            (long int) FLAC_SAMPLE_RATE, AV_ROUND_UP);
    ret = av_samples_alloc(outpb, &line_size, 2,
                    c_outsamples,MP3_SAMPLE_FMT, 0);
    av_assert0(ret >= 0);
    inpb[0] = buff;
    ret = swr_convert(swr, outpb, c_outsamples, inpb, c_insamples);
    av_assert0(ret >= 0);

    /*
     * encode
     */
    audio_frame_deccount +=(cbdec/4);
    printf("cbdec=%d, deccount=%d\n", cbdec, audio_frame_deccount);
    eframe->nb_samples = cbdec/(4);
    eframe->pts = (audio_frame_deccount * ( av_rescale_q(1, audio_encstream->codec->time_base, audio_encstream->time_base)));
    avcodec_fill_audio_frame(eframe, 2, MP3_SAMPLE_FMT, outpb[0], cbdec, 1);


    epkt.stream_index = audio_encstream->index;
    eframe->nb_samples = audio_enc_ctx->frame_size;

    ret = avcodec_encode_audio2(audio_enc_ctx, &epkt, eframe, &got_frame);
    av_assert0(ret >= 0);
    if (!got_frame)
    {
//      av_free(outpb[0]);
        return false;
    }
    epkt.stream_index = audio_encstream->index;
    audio_frame_enccount ++ ;
    /* Write the compressed frame to the media file. */
    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(encfmt_ctx, &epkt);


    av_free(outpb[0]);
    avcodec_free_frame(&eframe);
    return true;

}


int open_encodec_context(AVFormatContext *fmt_ctx, enum AVMediaType type)
{
    int ret;
    AVStream *st;
    AVCodec *enc = NULL;
    enc = avcodec_find_encoder(fmt_ctx->oformat->audio_codec);
    av_assert0(enc != NULL);
    st = avformat_new_stream(fmt_ctx, enc);
    /* find encoder for the stream */
    st->codec->sample_fmt = MP3_SAMPLE_FMT;
    st->codec->bit_rate = MP3_BITRATE;
    st->codec->sample_rate = MP3_SAMPLE_RATE;
    st->codec->channels = 2;
    ret = avcodec_open2(st->codec, enc, NULL);
    av_assert0(ret >= 0);


    return 1;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    const char *fn_out = argv[1];
    int ret;

    av_register_all();
    ret = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&encfmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, fn_out);
    av_assert0(ret >= 0);
    if (open_encodec_context(encfmt_ctx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) >= 0)
    {

        audio_encstream = encfmt_ctx->streams[0];
        audio_enc_ctx = audio_encstream->codec;
        av_dump_format(encfmt_ctx, 0, fn_out, 1);
    }

    BYTE pbo[sizeof(BYTE*) * av_sample_fmt_is_planar(MP3_SAMPLE_FMT) ? 2 : 1];
    outpb = (BYTE**) pbo;
    outpb[0] = NULL;
    BYTE pbi[sizeof(BYTE*) * 2];
    inpb = (const BYTE**) pbi;
    inpb[0] = NULL;
    swr = swr_alloc();
    av_assert0(swr);

    /* set options */
    av_opt_set_int(swr, "in_channel_layout", 2, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swr, "in_channel_count", 2, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swr, "in_sample_rate", FLAC_SAMPLE_RATE,0);
    av_opt_set_sample_fmt(swr, "in_sample_fmt", FLAC_SAMPLE_FMT, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swr, "out_channel_layout",2, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swr, "out_sample_rate", MP3_SAMPLE_RATE, 0);
    av_opt_set_sample_fmt(swr, "out_sample_fmt",MP3_SAMPLE_FMT, 0);
    ret = swr_init(swr);
    av_assert0(ret >= 0);

    if (!(encfmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    {
        ret = avio_open(&encfmt_ctx->pb, fn_out, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not open '%s': %s\n", fn_out,
                    av_err2str(ret));
            return 1;
        }
    }
    ret = avformat_write_header(encfmt_ctx, NULL);
    av_assert0(ret >= 0);

    int cbread = 0;
    int fd = open("/nas/temp/flac.raw", O_RDONLY);
    assert(fd > 0);
    int cb2read = BYTES_TO_READ;
    BYTE    b[cb2read];
    int c_reads = 0;
    while ((cbread = read(fd, b, cb2read)) > 0)
    {
        c_reads++;
        encode_buffer(b, cbread, false);
    }
    close(fd);
    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(encfmt_ctx, NULL);
    av_assert0(ret >= 0);

    av_write_trailer(encfmt_ctx);
    avio_close(encfmt_ctx->pb);

    avcodec_close(audio_enc_ctx);
    avformat_free_context(encfmt_ctx);
    exit(1);
}
```

The input data is from a decoded flac file (ie, the raw audio data from it). It is, according to libav/ffmpeg: format=s16, sample rate=44100, channels=2.

Any ideas?

TIA

ken

Comment: Perhaps the source is just avantgarde death metal dubstep?